# Share via Google+..dialog complete action with shown

Tags: android, android-intent, google-plus

hi everybody i've a little problem..i'm trying to share a text using google plus app, but the lastest version give me a problem.
when i call with an intent "com.google.android.apps.plus", android display me this dialog

[image]

so if i choose the first one, text will be shared correctly, but the second one do nothing.
if the app is not intalled i redirect the user to the market, at g+ download page (this work fine)

```
if (v == plus) {

                social(2);
                targetedShareIntent.putExtra(
                        android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, user);
                targetedShareIntent

                        .setPackage("com.google.android.apps.plus");
                startActivity(targetedShareIntent);

        }
```

"v" is a button and social check if app is installed
any sugestion?

Answer (score 0):

both options open google+ application?

I suppose show two options because google+ app have two activities with category.LAUNCHER.... the app and the chat app

[image: google plus launchers]

PSDT: sorry for my bad english!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the G+ dialog to launch with the following code (after querying the package manager to make sure the app was actually installed and passing in the currentContext as a parameter):

```
Intent appIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
String shareText = "Share text goes here";
appIntent.setType("text/plain");
appIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareText);

//Filters so only the G+ app will launch
appIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.plus");
try {
   currentContext.startActivity(appIntent);
} catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException e) {
    Log.d(e.getMessage());
}
```

Drove me bananas figuring this out, so I figured I'd try to save someone else the hassle.